# Facebook PHP SDK - Questions about accessing information / logging out

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk, logout

i want to connect a customer's website to Facebook using the PHP sdk (newest version). Visitors should be able to sign up using their Facebook account in order to be logged in automatically on the page itself if they are already logged in at Facebook, being identified by their profile ID which is saved in my database.

Here are my questions:

1. If I visit a website (which is using Facebook Login) for the first time, will this website be able to recognize whether I am logged in in Facebook or not, if I have not granted the permissions to the corresponding Facebook app yet?
2. If I have granted the permissions to the app and the page recognizes me as being logged in at Facebook, what does happen if I call the logout function of the PHP sdk? Will I only get disconnected from Facebook on the current page or will I get logged out on Facebook, too?

Answer (score 1):

1. This was the case a year or so ago, but now - without permissions - you don't know who the user is. ([Facebook authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/))
2. You will be logged out of Facebook too. ([Facebook getLogoutUrl](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/))